# tuple object has no attribute stat

Tags: python, python-2.7

**How do we use the os.walk() to find the files which are older than 5 minutes in a directory.
Is there any other way to find without os.walk() in python2.7 version
I want to implement using the try block in my script.**

```
import os
import time
dir = '\\Users\\ramya\\scripts\\'
# here we define the function
def validate_file_status(dir):
  #file_status = False
  BlockedFiles = []
  try:
     obj_FileDir = os.walk(dir)
     for entry in obj_FileDir:
       age = time.time() - entry.stat().st_mtime
       if (entry.is_file()) and (age > 300):
           BlockedFiles = os.path.join(entry.name)
  except Exception as e:
        print(e)
  print(BlockedFiles)
validate_file_status(dir)
```

**Expecting to print the output in the below format::**
oldfiles 2246342.382509947
list.py 5782357.565317392
files.py 2248789.355661154

Comment: Your title line seems to be unrelated to your question.

Comment: `os.walk` yields tuple of three elements. [`(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Hi @KlausD , I'm very new to python. right now I'm using the os.walk() how do we fix the above error(tuple object has no attribute stat). Also i wanted to try it in other way round  to get my output without os.walk ().

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM has identified your problem. Please look at the `os.walk` example [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to see how to correctly use this method.

Comment: Also, why are you using Python 2.7? Are you forced to?

Comment: I used scandir() which worked perfectly. As part of learning currently i'm trying with os.walk() and also os.list(). @ndc85430

Comment: But Python 2 is out of date. If you're learning, you should be using 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You should be working with Python 3 (current version is 3.11.5). The so-called "sunset" date for Python 2 was 1st January 2020 - i.e., it is no longer supported.

You should familiarise yourself with the *pathlib* module and, in particular for your case, its *glob()* functionality.

Something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
from time import time
from typing import Generator

DIRECTORY = Path('/Users/ramya/scripts')
AGE = 300 # seconds

# find all files in directory older than age seconds
# use recursive parameter as required
def old_files(directory: Path, age: int, recursive: bool = False) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    for entry in directory.glob('**/*' if recursive else '*'):
        if entry.is_file():
            if (time() - entry.stat().st_mtime) > age:
                yield entry.absolute()

for file in old_files(DIRECTORY, AGE):
    print(file)
```